# Походження фразеологізму "ні кола, ні двора"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Про дуже бідну людину кажуть "ні кола, ні двора".

Таке ж значення знайшла в [Фразеологічному словнику української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53396/357179.html)

> ***ні кола́, ні двора́*** в кого і без додатка. 1. Хто-небудь дуже бідний, злиденний. То ледар, волоцюга. Йому (Василеві) теряти
>   (втрачати) нічого, у його ні кола, ні двора, а в мене — он город,..
>   вибудував хату (Панас Мирний)

Цікавить походження даного фразеологізму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На одному із освітніх [сайтів](https://naurok.com.ua/slovnik-frazeologizmiv-dlya-uchniv-ta-uchiteliv-17527.html):

> Давні слов'яни колом називали землю, бо й огороджували кілками. На коли ділили луги, сінокост. Та деякі дослідники стверджуюють, що у фразеологізмі "ні кола ні двора" кіл - це кілок для огорожі. Він став символом злиднів і бідності. У людии,  якої не було огорожі, навіть кілка для неї, отже, не було й двору, який потрібно огороджувати. Тому про бідняків часто кажуть "у нього ні кола ні двора".

Точнішу інформацію знаходимо при тлумаченні російського фразеологізму ["Ни кола, ни двора"](http://www.fraze.ru/index.php/frazeologizm/na-bukvu-n/ni-kola-ni-dvora):

> [переклад] Колом в XIX столітті називали смужку орної землі шириною в два сажні (близько 4 метрів).
>   Не мати кола означало не мати ріллі; не мати двору - означає не мати дому і жити у інших.